# Proving that $\int_0^{\pi/2} \sin^{2n + 1}(x) dx = \frac{2}{3} \cdot \frac{4}{5} \cdot \frac{6}{7} \cdot ... \cdot\frac{2n}{2n + 1}$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, trigonometric-integrals

I'm having some trouble with the following exercice:

> Prove that, for all $n \in \Bbb N$: $$\int_0^{\pi/2} \sin^{2n + 1}(x) dx = \frac{2}{3} \cdot \frac{4}{5} \cdot \frac{6}{7} \cdot ... \cdot\frac{2n}{2n + 1}$$

So, the first thing I did was write the rhs using the product notation no make things a little easier:

$$\frac{2}{3} \cdot \frac{4}{5} \cdot \frac{6}{7} \cdot ... \cdot\frac{2n}{2n + 1} = \prod_{k=1}^n \frac{2k}{2k + 1}$$

And then I tried to use induction to prove this and I easily proved that if $n = 1$ this is true, But I'm having some trouble with the induction step of the proof. How can I prove this?

Note: In the last exercice the I proved that:

$$\int \sin^n(x) dx = - \frac{1}{n}(\sin^{n - 1}(x))\cos(x) + \frac{n - 1}{n} \int \sin^{n - 2}(x) dx$$

I don't know if this helps or if it's related to this exercise.

Comment: I can at least hint that the last exercise 100% helps with this exercise...! What happens if you change that indefinite integral identity (the one you got via integration by parts) to a definite integral identity?

Answer (score 2):

The proof you have done in your previous exercise, as you mentioned is exactly what you can use to get you answer for your question. A small step and you reach you answer. In you answer, if you take the integral on left hand side *I**{n} the integrals with exponential powers (n-1) and (n-2) get simplified into *I**{n-1} and *I*_{n-2} the you can form a series which will give you the value you require.

Forgive my typing as I am new to stackexchange.
Hope this  helps!

Comment: Small steps in the right direction can turn to be the biggest steps in your life. Kindly peruse the easy MathJax tutorial [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33179/short-and-helpful-advice-on-using-mathjax-on-the-site) for your conveniences, and leave feedback at the end if you wish to in the form of a comment. Thank you for your contributions, and if you wish to expand on your answer using MathJax you may do so. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need only prove$$\begin{align}0&=\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin^{2n-1}x(2n-1-2n\sin^2x)dx\\&=\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin^{2n-1}x(2n\cos^2x-1)dx\\&=[\sin^{2n}x\cos x]_0^{\pi/2}.\end{align}$$